# keep @Throws kotlin annotation in proguard?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, proguard

I'm seeing the following compiler error in a client app (java) of my library (kotlin):

```
error: exception MyCustomException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
            catch (MyCustomException e)
```

But I only see this error when the client app is consuming the release build of my library

Client app:

```
try {
    myLibClassInstance.doSomething()
} catch (MyCustomException e) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Library:

```
class MyLibClass {

    @Throws(MyCustomException::class)
    fun doSomething() {
        throw MyCustomException()
    }
}
```

There is clearly a library method being called from the client app that is marked with `@Throws(MyCustomException::class)`. Further evidenced by the fact that this again only happens when consuming a release build of the library.

So my assumption here is that the `@Throws` annotation is being stripped out leaving the client java code to have no way of knowing its method call can throw a `MyCustomException`.

**Is there a way to keep the `@Throws` annotation through proguard?** I've already tried `-keepattributes *Annotation*` and `-keep class kotlin.**`, but neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-keepattributes Exceptions` fixed the issue.

https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/attributes

> **Exceptions**
>
> Specifies the exceptions that a method may throw. Compilers
> may use this information to enforce catching them.